# Specs satisfying the Firebase/Analytics, Firebase/Analytics (~> 8.0) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

This is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!

# workaround to avoid Xcode 10 caching of Pods that requires
# Product -> Clean Build Folder after new Cordova plugins installed
# Requires CocoaPods 1.6 or newer
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

def capacitor_pods
  pod 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCordova', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCommunityFacebookLogin', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor-community/facebook-login'
  pod 'CapacitorCommunityFcm', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor-community/fcm'
  pod 'CapacitorCommunityFirebaseAnalytics', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor-community/firebase-analytics'
  pod 'CapacitorApp', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/app'
  pod 'CapacitorAppLauncher', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/app-launcher'
  pod 'CapacitorBrowser', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/browser'
  pod 'CapacitorCamera', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/camera'
  pod 'CapacitorDevice', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/device'
  pod 'CapacitorHaptics', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/haptics'
  pod 'CapacitorKeyboard', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard'
  pod 'CapacitorPushNotifications', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/push-notifications'
  pod 'CapacitorStatusBar', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/status-bar'
  pod 'CapacitorStorage', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/storage'
  pod 'CordovaPlugins', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
end

target 'App' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here
  # # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 7.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 12.0.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 12.0.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 12.0.0'
  
  # add pods for any other desired Firebase products
  # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
end
```

A week ago it worked perfectly, but I don't know if they released an update that doesn't work now, if someone passed it, can you help me? I tried to change the minim, but it said the same error, I tried doing pod install --repo-update , it didn't work either.

The error:

````
        Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
        
        CocoaPods 1.11.2 is available.
        To update use: `gem install cocoapods`
        
        For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.11.2
        
        [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics":
        In Podfile:
        CapacitorCommunityFirebaseAnalytics (from `../../node_modules/@capacitor-community/firebase-analytics`) was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
        Firebase/Analytics (~> 8.0)
        
        Firebase/Analytics
        
        Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Analytics, Firebase/Analytics (~> 8.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
        
==> Script finished with exit code: 1 ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Remove `, '~> 7.9.0'` from the Podfile.

It's incompatible with Firebase/Analytics 8.x required by `CapacitorCommunityFirebaseAnalytics`

Comment: After I followed your instructions, I get a new error:  CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit":
  In Podfile:
    CapacitorCommunityFacebookLogin (from `../../node_modules/@capacitor-community/facebook-login`) was resolved to 3.1.1, which depends on
      FBSDKCoreKit (~> 11.0.0)

    FBSDKCoreKit (~> 12.0.0)

Specs satisfying the `FBSDKCoreKit (~> 12.0.0), FBSDKCoreKit (~> 11.0.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.